# Arduino LED RGB Control and Convert Hex to RGB

Tags: colors, arduino, hex, rgb, led

I have an RGB LED and have pins to 9, 10, 11 and a pin to ground.

What's I have to do, is to control this LED and light it up with a HEXADECIMAL color choosed in the Serial Monitor.

```
    int redPin = 9;    // the pin that the red LED is attached to
    int greenPin = 10; // the pin that the green LED is attached to
    int bluePin = 11; // the pin that the blue LED is attached to


void setup(){
             Serial.begin(115200);
             pinMode(4,OUTPUT);
             pinMode(redPin, OUTPUT);
             pinMode(greenPin, OUTPUT);
             pinMode(bluePin, OUTPUT);
             Serial.println("Bonjour");
             digitalWrite(4,HIGH);
}

        void loop(){



      while(Serial.available()){

   Serial.begin(115200);

for(int i=0;i<5;i++){

  hexstring[i] = Serial.read();

}
int number = (int) strtol( &hexstring, NULL, 16);
int r = number >> 16;
int g = number >> 8 & 0xFF;
int b = number & 0xFF;

        colorRGB(redInt,greenInt,blueInt);
}




     void colorRGB(int red, int green, int blue){
             analogWrite(redPin,constrain(red,0,255));
             analogWrite(greenPin,constrain(green,0,255));
             analogWrite(bluePin,constrain(blue,0,255));

        }
```

1st erreur in this line :

```
int number = (int) strtol( &hexstring, NULL, 16)
```

I wanted to try just the first part by picking up and HEX color :

```
 String hexstring = "#FFFFFF";
    int number = (int) strtol( &hexstring[1], NULL, 16);
    int r = number >> 16;
    int g = number >> 8 & 0xFF;
    int b = number & 0xFF;
```

No Error but the LED don't light up !
Could anyone help me ?! PLEASE !!

Comment: Was there error while compiling code? At least your code does not declare hexstring at all.

Comment: What error? You are missing a `}`. `while(Serial.available()){` only checks if there is at least 1 byte in the serial buffer, but you are reading 5 bytes anyway. An `int` is only 2 bytes. I don't see `hexstring` being defined anywhere. You don't null terminate the `hexstring`. Or is it a `String` object? Does `strtol` even accept a `String` object?

Comment: My bad, I just didn't made some errors while copying the code that I've executed, but all the comments mentioned above where already done : I have declared the hexstring like this : char hexstring[10];      The problem is that the led light up in just one color (Red,green,blue) and don't change. i think the problem is in the conversion from HEX to RGB !!